# Adding decimal string and rounding to the nearest .05

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to add a bunch of string this may or may not have decimal values. After adding them up I want to round the number to the near Canadian currency rounding standard since the penny has been dropped.

The rounding looks something like this

**Round Down**

1.01 or 1.02 = 1.00

1.06 or 1.07 = 1.05

**Round Up**

1.03 or 1.04 = 1.05

1.08 or 1.09 = 1.10

So far I've got my js to code to look something like this.

```
var total1 = null;
var total2 = null;

var num1 = 144.02;
var num2 = 43.09;

var num3 = 1344.04;
var num4 = 443.07;

total1 = parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2);
console.log(total1);

total1 = parseFloat(num3) + parseFloat(num4);
console.log(total2);
```

Fiddle Link http://jsfiddle.net/Lg6bj5vp/

Any help on how to proceed from here would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at [``Math.round()``](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)?  I think that may be what you're looking for.

Comment: A bit of unsolicited advise: try not to use floating point numbers for money values in Javascript. You'll run into the same problems as with other languages. There are some very nice decimal number libraries for Javascript out there.

Comment: @abl Thank you for the advise! can you recommend me some?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lg6bj5vp/1/

Comment: @BaconJuice take a look: [Is there a good Javascript BigDecimal library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744099/is-there-a-good-javascript-bigdecimal-library)

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```js
(Math.round(num*20)/20).toFixed(2)
```

`Math.round(num)` returns `num` rounded to the nearest integer.

Therefore, `Math.round(num*20)/20` returns `num` rounded to the nearest `1/20 = 0.05`.

Finally, `num.toFixed(2)` returns `num` converted to string with two decimals.

Comment: (Math.round(number / 0.05) * 0.05).toFixed(2)

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseNumString(str) {
    var significant = parseFloat(str).toFixed(2);
    var lastDigit = significant.substr(significant.length -1);
    var secondToLast = significant.slice(significant.length -1, significant.length -1);
    if (lastDigit = '1' || lastDigit == '2') {
        string = significant.slice(0, significant.length - 2) + secondToLast + '0';
    } else if (lastDigit == '3' ||
               lastDigit == '4' ||
               lastDigit == '6' ||
               lastDigit == '7' ||) {
        string = significant.slice(0, significant.length - 2) + secondToLast + '5';
    } else if (lastDigit == '8' || lastDigit == '9') {
        string = significant.slice(0, significant.length - 2) + 
                (+secondToLast + 1).toString() + '0';
    } else {
        string = significant;
    }

    return +string;
```

}